sylog-ng installed via Dockerfile forces Python snmp calls to stop working post remote server restart (manual snmp calls working fine)
dockerfile relevant code:
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && \
apt-get upgrade -y && \
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y syslog-ng

using python code - i am getting values via snmp
from netsnmp import *
res = snmpget(Varbind(tag='some_tag', iid=0),
                 DestHost='192.168.1.10',
                 Version=3,
                 SecLevel='authPriv',
                 SecName='user',
                 PrivProto='DES',
                 PrivPass='pswd123456',
                 AuthProto='MD5',
                 AuthPass='pswd123456',
                 Timeout=60,
                 Retries=1)
if isinstance(res, tuple) and len(res) == 1:
            res = res[0]    
print(f'result {repr(res)}')

# print before clearing remote server config
    result b'some valid value'

# print after clearing remote server config
    result None

# manual call works fine all the time   
#but even after clearing remote server config following works

    snmpget -v3 -l authPriv -u admin -a MD5 -A "pswd123456" -x DES -X "pswd123456" 192.168.1.10 some_mib_name.0
    <mib_hrchy>::<resolved_mib_name>.iid = STRING: some valid value

What could stop the python snmp from being executed when manual snmp calls work absolutely fine?
